# Observables with nested reactive form Angular 5

Tags: angular, observable, angular-reactive-forms

I have reactive form like this:

```
<form *ngIf="people$ | async;" [formGroup]="applicationForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">

  <person-form
    [parentForm]="applicationForm"
    (added)="addPerson()"
    (removed)="removePerson($event)">
  </person-form>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

And an appropriate class

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  applicationForm: FormGroup;
  people$: Observable<any>;

  constructor( public peopleService: PeopleService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.applicationForm = this.fb.group({});

    this.people$ = this.peopleService.getPeopleData().pipe(
      tap(peopleData => {
        this.applicationForm.setControl('people', this.fb.array(peopleData || []));
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Im my ngOnInit I'm getting data from service which gives me array of people and pushing to applicationForm as form Controls. The problem occurs when I pass that applicationForm to nested form in array:
Here is the template of nested form:

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <div formArrayName="people">
    <div *ngFor="let item of people; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <input type="number" formControlName="age" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a class of nested form

```
export class BorrowerFormComponent {
  @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
  @Output() added: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() removed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  onAdd() {
    this.added.emit();
  }

  onRemove(index) {
    this.removed.emit(index);
  }

  get people() {
    return (this.parentForm.get('people') as FormArray).controls;
  }
}
```

I also emit some adding and removing array elements, I omit this to make code shorter
So Ii shows me control after long period of time but also I have error:

```
Cannot find control with path: 'people -> 0 -> age'
```

Did I miss something? Why it cannot find 'people -> 0 -> age'?
This 'age' field is returned from service.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare "age" in your formControl

```
ngOnInit(){

    initGroup() {
        let rows = this.parentForm.get('people') as FormArray;
        rows.push(this.fb.group({
          age: [null, Validators.required],
        }))   
     } 
}
```

Comment: Where this should be added? In parent form ngOnInit?
I did like this in parent component and still have same error:
    this.applicationForm = this.fb.group({
      people: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          age: null,
        })
      ])
    });

Comment: @Luchnik. Please check again

Comment: It doesn't work. When I do let rows = this.parentForm.get('people') as FormArray;
It gives me array of FormControls with appropriate data from service (including age). But when pushing new formGroup - the resulted array looks like this:
[FormControl, FormControl, FormGroup] which is not what we need

Comment: Can you replicate this in stackblitz?